# How to select a Particur date in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, calendar

[image: How to select a particular date]

Help me select a particular date from this calendar in selenium webdriver

Comment: Could you share HTML for this calendar as well??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-empty ng-valid-date ng-touched" type="text" is-open="fromDatepicker" ng-click="fromDatepicker = !fromDatepicker" ng-model="createAbsence.startDate" ng-change="monitorEndDate('fromDate',createAbsence.selectedAbsenceType)" uib-datepicker-popup="dd MMM yyyy" min-date="createAbsence.minimumDate" placeholder="Select From Date" ng-keydown="$event.preventDefault()" style="">

Comment: But this is the HTML of text box, We need HTML of date picker..

Comment: Ok could you confirm in which date format date shows into textbox when you are selecting the date from showing calendar means like this `26/08/2016` or other format??

Comment: it will shows like 26 Aug 2016

Comment: i am not able use sendkeys also :(

Comment: <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar link-cursor pull-right" ng-click="fromDatepicker = !fromDatepicker" style="margin-top: -15px;"></i>

Comment: thats the html code of date picker @SaurabhGaur

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121882/discussion-between-boopathi-and-saurabh-gaur).

Comment: Why not able with `sendkeys`?? Is there any exception??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using `JavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value = '26 Aug 2016'", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder = 'Select From Date']")))
```

Comment: Bro i got one more problem  @Saurabh